# Using Lists of objects

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Okay, so this might be a strange question, but here goes.  The following code is
very generic pseudo code, but this would be done in C#.

Let's say you have a class as follows:

```
public class Animal()
{
various methods and members here...

public Animals getSpecificAnimal(ref animalList,animalType, ref int whichAnimal)
{
//The logic in here will find your specifi animal, as well as the index of it in the list 

return Animal;
}

public void replaceSpecifiAnimal(ref animalList,Animal newAnimal, int whichAnimal)
{
//The assumption here is that you know the index of the specific animal you
//want to replace in the list.

animalList.RemoveAt(whichAnimal);
animalList.Add(newAnimal);

 }
}

public class Cat:Animal
{
}

public class Dog:Animal
{
}

public class Fish:Animal
{
}
```

Now, you've created at list of these animals as follows and are using it in some class:

```
var animalList = new List<Animal>();
```

Then you've added some animals to it, say, a Dog, Cat and a Fish.  Now, however, you'd like to replace the Fish with a different fish, so you do this:

```
animalList[0].getSpecificAnimal(ref animalList, Fish,ref whichAnimal);

animalList[0].replaceSpecifiAnimal(ref animalList,newFish,whichAnimal);
```

This will replace your old fish with the new one.

So now to the question: What are the dangers in using something in a list to mod the list?

This code, well... the real version of it, works.  It compiles and runs just fine.  But I just
can't help feeling as if I'm courting a danger that's greater than just a little obfuscation.  It should
be noted that the code will work even if (in this case) Fish is in index zero.

There are reasons why I coded this the way I did.  I could put the methods that act on animalList in 
a different class, but the advantage of not doing that is that I can pass animalList around (once it's been populated), and it's all self contained.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why are you using `ref` at all?

Comment: In first place why are you using `ref`?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what `ref` does/is used for?

Comment: Yes, guys, I screwed up by adding ref.  That kinda wasn't the question though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my thoughts.

---

Declare `getSpecificAnimal` and `replaceSpecifiAnimal` as static methods.

```
public static void replaceSpecifiAnimal(...)
```

That way you can call them without an instance like so

```
Animal.replaceSpecifiAnimal(...);
```

---

get rid of all the `ref` keywords.  They do absolutely nothing for you in your example.

Comment: and yes, I know about extension methods, but the OP has to understand how static methods work in the first place before going there

Comment: The ref int is required, since I'm modifying the variable for use elsewhere, however, the ref for the objects is not.

Comment: Oh, and (head-desk) I should have thought of using a static method!  Thanks for that.

Comment: @Cynon why are you changing **anything**, let alone the index to search, in a method that begins with the word **"get"**

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us some context on what code uses this?  It looks to me like you just need to find the first animal of a given type.  Since you're using C# 4.0, you can easily use LINQ for that.

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>{new Cat(), new Dog(), new Fish()};
Animal fish = animals.First(a => a is Fish);
animals.Remove(animals.First(a => a is Cat));
animals.Add(new Cat());
```

Also, definitely get rid of the ref parameters.  In most cases of C# you don't need them, and it's clear in this case that you're not familiar with their correct usage.